# Convert from space to comma and reorder the values Python

Tags: python

I have a .csv file with many lines and with the structure:

```
YYY-MM-DD HH first_name quantity_number second_name first_number second_number third_number
```

I have a script in python to convert the separator from space to comma, and that working fine.

```
import csv
with open('file.csv') as infile, open('newfile.dat', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        outfile.write(" ".join(line.split()).replace(' ', ','))
```

I need change, in the newfile.dat, the position of each value, for example put the HH value in position 6, the second_name value in position 2, etc.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please post your code by indenting each line 4 spaces with a newline before & after your code.

Comment: What is your question? SO is not a free code generator. We don't do your work for you.

Comment: You might find it easier to use the built-in `csv` package rather than parsing and writing the file by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're import `csv` might as well use it

```
import csv
with open('file.csv', newline='') as infile, open('newfile.dat', 'w+', newline='') as outfile:
    read = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=' ')
    write = csv.writer(outfile) #defaults to excel format, ie commas
    for line in read:
        write.writerow(line)
```

Use `newline=''` when opening csv files, otherwise you get double spaced files.

This just writes the line as it is in the input.  If you want to change it before writing, do it in the `for line in read:` loop.  `line` is a list of strings, which you can change the order of in any number of ways.

One way to reorder the values is to use `operator.itemgetter`:

```
from operator import itemgetter
getter = itemgetter(5,4,3,2,1,0) #This will reverse a six_element list
for line in read:
     write.writerow(getter(line))
```

Comment: OP want to modify value before writing to file - need change, in the newfile.dat, the position of each value, for example put the HH value in position 6, the second_name value in position 2, etc

Comment: @DineshPundkar without knowing the exact transform he's looking for it's hard to help.

Comment: @DineshPundkar, yes, I only that need to change the position of the values. The values continue with same value of the original file, but in different position in the newfile.

Answer (score 1):

To reorder the items, a basic way could be as follows:

```
split_line = line.split(" ")
column_mapping = [9,6,3,7,3,2,1]
reordered = [split_line[c] for c in column_mapping]
joined = ",".join(reordered)
outfile.write(joined)
```

This splits up the string, reorders it according to `column_mapping` and then combines it back into one string (comma separated)

(in your code don't include `column_mapping` in the loop to avoid reinitialising it)